# win11, lazarus, brookframework, libsagui-3.dll with tls doesn't work?

Tags: freepascal, web-frameworks

Problem solved under the help from author of brookframework.

To use tls, these [files](https://github.com/risoflora/libsagui/releases/download/v3.4.4/gnutls-3.8.3-mingw_amd64.zip) should be also put in the same folder of libsagui-3.dll

---

An error happened with the message:

> libsagui-3.dll is not loaded

I tried to build the demo project of brookframework/Examples/Console/FPC
/hellohttpsrv.lpr with Lazarus v3.0 on Win 11 and have `libsagui-3.dll` (tls_win_amd64 version) in the project folder.

I then download libsagui-3.5.0-windows_amd64.zip and put the libsagui-3.dll without tls in the project folder. The program works!

So, I guess there is something wrong with tls_win_amd64 version dll?

Comment: That's a solution without explaining anything - what's the difference of your approach vs. which exact files the framework author wants you to use? Also: take the [tour] and learn the difference between a question and an answer (yes, you can create an answer to your own question). Consider adding the tag `lazarus` to your Q to make it much more visible to others.